# Reinstall Windows without key, unable to boot into the old install

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, boot, reinstall

I have tried everything, but I just can't boot into my Windows 7 install. Repairing and all of that didn't work. I don't have a Windows CD, but I downloaded the ISO image and burned it onto an USB thumb drive. I also don't have the key, I could look it up, when in Windows, but now I have no idea of how to get it back. So is there a way to re install Windows without knowing the key of the old install or is there a way of retrieving that old key?

Also is there a way of getting my files back? I tried to use Linux, but I didn't have access to the Windows hard drive. Do I have to install Linux? I only tried it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: All Windows 7 devices are required to have a COA with the license key contained on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did in the end:

I used a linux live CD to get my files back and moved the `Windows/System32/config` folder onto a USB flash driver. Using Produkey by Nirsoft (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html), which I installed on another Windows computer, I was able to extract the key out of the `config` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Before reinstalling without a key you may want to try this--assuming you have not "tried everything".

Download a [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd) (a Linux OS used to fix boot problems) and burn it to a disk if you have a disk drive or use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to get it to a USB thumb drive.

Then boot to that disk/USB using your BIOS if necessary.

Getting into BIOS requires you to mash F2 or F12 or DEL depending on your computer's setup BEFORE the OS is loaded when turning on or rebooting you computer.

Follow the prompts and try the 'recommended repair' option:

Comment: As far as I understand, this tool only repairs Linux operating systems, am I wrong?

Comment: I use it on windows boot problems too and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't deleted your partition and have not installed new windows then try this to get rid of boot fix problems:

```
1.Boot windows from DVD or flash drive make sure you are booting the same window version and same architecture like if installed version is windows 8 64bit then flash or DVD must have the same.


2.Go windows install menu but do not click on install now but click repair computer and then go to Troubleshoot option and advance option and then command prompt.


3.On command prompt type bootrec.exe /FixMbr and press enter .


4.Then Type bootrec.exe /FixBoot and press enter.


5.Exit the command prompt and reboot computer.
```

If it recovers the windows boot then fine. If not follow the below process:

```
1.Type diskpart and press enter.
2.Type listdisk and press enter.
3.Type select disk <disk number 0 ,1 ,2 ..> (the partition number where windows is installed)
4.Type list partition and press enter.
5.Type select partition <partition number 0,1,2...> . (the partition number where windows is installed)
6.Type active and press enter.
```

Close the command prompt and raboot the windows it will bring the winsows up.

**Now the next question**: You can get your data for that you have to do following:

- Download any Linux live CD(preferably Ubuntu 14.04).
- Burn it on DVD or usb flash drive.
- Boot from DVD or flash drive.
- After booting click on Try without installing.
  You will get the Ubuntu desktop with your windows partition mounted. Double click on Drive icon in menu and see your content there. If not mounted then mount using mount command.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got another Windows machine available, you can try hooking up the drive to that machine, and accessing the data through Windows Explorer.